# I tried simple can & dog image classification in tensorflow and suddenly mess with problem. please could you please help me to solve this?

Tags: tensorflow, resize, opencv, image-classification, python

I got following error when exciting this function,
error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1bq9o88m\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize

```
for img in os.listdir(folder):
    img_path = os.path.join(folder, img)
    img_arr  = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(img_path), (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the shape of you input images and what are the minimum and maximum pixel values.
It appears cv2.imread is not reading the image. Try using debug code below:

```
for img in os.listdir(folder):
    img_path = os.path.join(folder, img)
    print (img_path)
    try:
        input_img=cv2.imread(img_path)
        img_shape=input_img.shape
        print ( img_shape)
    except:
        print(' image was not read in')
```

Comment: First, Thank you for your help!!! It's printed the shape and the image path as follows:                
C:\Users\hnhas\Downloads\AI Data\kagglecatsanddogs_3367a\PetImages\Cat\0.jpg
(375, 500, 3)

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue there.
In here some images are broken, so resizing failed to run.
I used following function to pass the broken images,

```
        try:
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
            new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) 
            training_data.append([new_array, class_num]) 
        except Exception as e:  # in the interest in keeping the output clean...
            pass
```

Thank you for your help!!!